# ¿Se puede saber si un valor (número) está más cerca o más lejos de otro número?

Tags: javascript

Digamos que tengo este array de números:

```
 var numeros = [1,4,5,9,10,50,100,500,1000]
```

Quiero saber si se puede hacer algo sin mucha complicación (imagino que con If else se puede pero si añadiésemos más números en el array sería un caos) para que si le doy un `(num)` a una función me devuelva el número del array `numeros` que más cerca este de  `(num)`

Pseudo código que he pongo con los resultados que debería dar:

```js
 var numeros = [1,4,5,9,10,50,100,500,1000]

function closer(num){
    return numeros[el que más cerca este de (num)]
  
}

function closer(6)   // debería devolver 5
function closer(8)   // debería devolver 9
function closer(46)  // debería devolver 50
function closer(251) // debería devolver 500
```

Comment: aparentemente tu problema se puede resolver recorriendo cada uno de los numeros del array `numeros`, y calcular la diferencia absoluta entre el numero indicado en la funcion y el de la posicion. El que tenga un valor mas pequeño, es el que mas cerca del numero inicial se encuentra.

Comment: @Javier Cake, que sucede cuando esta cerca de dos numeros 3 y 7 y mi valor  buscado es 5, tomo el cercano menor o el  cercano mayor?

Comment: @MiguelZarate es para un problema concreto así que no se daría esa posibilidad de que estuviese entre 3 y 7. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una forma de hacer esto:

```js
var nums = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2],
  numero = 5;

var cercano = nums.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - numero) < Math.abs(prev - numero) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(cercano); // da 4
```

Prueba a ver si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Me parece que responder a preguntas  que están mal formuladas o en las que la persona que pregunta no se ha tomado la molestia de intentarlo (está esperando a que le solucionen el problema sin intentar solucionarlo antes, es por eso que esta pregunta esta con calificación negativa) hace que la calidad del contenido de stackoverflow español baje de nivel.

Comment: @clay Pido disculpas si redacté el hilo de alguna manera equivocada. Estoy aprendiendo aunque Realmente si lo había intentado antes aunque debo admitir que estaba realmente cansado y no me salía nada, quizás si lo hubiese intentado otro día lo hubiese sacado. Intentaré la próxima vez pensar un poco más las cosas aunque realmente la solución usando reduce es la que más utilidad me ha dado y en ese caso aseguro que no la hubiese sacado yo xD. Disculpas otra vez